# Making an <aside> element a specific part of a page?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm trying to make a page that involves 3 parts to a page - An aside element, a div element (to be used for animation but not relevant), and a footer. How I want it layed out is the aside element on the top left of the page, and the black div element below that, while a footer is just generally under the div element. What I have so far has the div element as almost a background for the aside element, and the footer below that.

When I try and do `position: absolute; top: xxx left: xxx` the div element will be positioned fine, but it will overlap overtop of the footer.

How do I get it to act differently? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A thing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="finalmobile.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and ( min-width: 30em )" href="finaltablet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and ( min-width: 48em )" href="final.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="project.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside class="aside1">
            <h1>TEXT</h1>
        </aside>
        <div class="coupon">
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <footer>
            <p style="font-size: small; text-align: center">&#169; Blah Blah Blah, 2017</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
aside.aside1                {
                                    height: 20%;
                                    width: 40%;
                                    margin: 2%;
                                    padding: 1%;
                                    background-color: teal;
                                    border: 1px solid black;
                                    float: left;
                                    border-radius: 5px;
            }
    div.coupon      {
                                    height: 20%;
                                    width: 50%;
                                    background-color: black;
                                    position: static;
                                    top: 40%;

            }
```

Comment: Can you post an image on how the layout *should* look like? Based on your description it's quite difficult to picture what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @Terry how exactly do I do that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/b0SnBld

Answer (score 1):

You can remove/avoid the `position: absolute` from the `.coupon` DIV (making/leaving it a regular element inside the document flow, thereby pushing subsequent elements like the footer down) and add `position: absolute` to the `aside`, thereby placing it above the DIV in the top left corner of the body (it will scroll along with the body if you scroll down).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

aside.aside1 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: teal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.coupon {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: static;
  top: 40%;
  color: white;
  padding: 150px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside1">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
</aside>
<div class="coupon">
  <p>If you put some content in here, you'll see that this element will grow.</p>
  <p>If you put some content in here, you'll see that this element will grow.</p>
  <p>If you put some content in here, you'll see that this element will grow.</p>
  <p>If you put some content in here, you'll see that this element will grow.</p>
  <p>If you put some content in here, you'll see that this element will grow.</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p style="font-size: small; text-align: center">&#169; Blah Blah Blah, 2017</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Didn't quite work for me, in fact it did nothing for me

Comment: without content, your coupon div won't be displayed - see the snippet i added

Comment: I don't want it to be fixed in the top left. When a user scrolls down it should behave normally

Comment: then just change it to `position: absolute` - see my changed answer and snippet